# How to efficiently compare two sets of unordered vectors (`np.ndarray`)?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, comparison, numpy-ndarray

I tried to make my question clearer. The old digression can still be found at the end of this.

**PROBLEM**: I have an `n` by 3 matrix `A` (`np.ndarray`) of `n` points in three dimensions. We say those points are symmetric in relation to a transformation `R` (3 by 3 matrix) if they are stationary as an unordered set.

This means that `A` and `A @ R.T` differ by 1. at most a permutation and 2. after corrected for permutation, both matrices might differ by a numerical tolerance parameter: `np.allclose(A, permuted(A @ R.T)) == True` (I don't know `permuted()` beforehand and this surely depends on `R`).

**QUESTION**: how do I create the following function:

```py
def is_symmetric(A, R, atol=1e-5) -> bool:
    # checks symmetry as defined above, considering both numerical noise
    # and permutation of vectors.
```

(Some discussion on possible ways and my doubts and attempts are to be found below.)

---

**OLD DIGRESSION**:

I want to check for symmetries in a collection of points, represented as vectors. That means checking whether those points are invariant regarding the application of a matrix transform in space, e.g., rotation or plane mirroring.

```py
import numpy as np
R = np.array([[0, -1, 0],  # 90° rotation around z as an example
              [1,  0, 0],
              [0,  0, 1]])
```

The point is that **I accept a permutation of the vectors**: as long as some initial position gets transformed to some other, preexisting, location, I'm fine. That means checking for transformed pairs of vectors from one to the other.

The *naïve solution* would be looping over the rows of `A @ R.T` (where `A` is a matrix whose rows are point positions) and try to match a transformed vector for each initial row of `A`, which seems to grow quadratically with the number of columns.

Another possibility would be *preordering the vectors* (say, by their coordinate values):

```py
A = np.array([[1,   0,   0],  # some points
              [0,   1,   0],
              [0,   0,   1],
              [0.5, 0.5, 0]])
A = np.array(sorted(A, key=lambda v: (v[2], v[1], v[0])))  # sort by z, y, x values
# array([[1. , 0. , 0. ],
#        [0.5, 0.5, 0. ],
#        [0. , 1. , 0. ],
#        [0. , 0. , 1. ]])

A_rotated = np.array(sorted(A @ R.T, key=lambda v: (v[2], v[1], v[0])))
# array([[-1. ,  0. ,  0. ],   # no match
#        [-0.5,  0.5,  0. ],   # no match
#        [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ],   # match
#        [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ]])  # match
```

(This approach does two sorts so O(n ln(n))?)
The third idea would be to *compare sets* created from the original and rotated vectors. I have a gut feeling that this is as good as comparing sorted vectors.

But one thing remains: how to deal with approximate comparison? I want to accept two vectors `v` and `w` being equal if e.g. `np.allclose(v, w) == True` or equivalent (i.e., `abs(v - w) < eps` or similar):

```py
np.allclose([1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0])
# True
np.allclose([1, 0, 0], [1 + 1e-5, 0, 0], atol=1e-5)
# True
np.allclose([1, 0, 0], [1 + 1e-4, 0, 0], atol=1e-5)
# False
```

**So here is the question**: how do I (efficiently) compare two (unordered) sets of vectors for equality, taking numerical approximation (e.g. `np.allclose`) into account?

Comment: Please be more precise and explain what do you mean by `isclose()`, and provide an example.

Comment: @CatalinaChircu I edited to better expose what I mean. I made some confusion with `isclose`, I meant `allclose` (I'm comparing two different `ndarray`s as single entities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that works using `np.lexsort`:

```py
def is_symmetric(A, R, *args, **kwargs):
    A = np.asanyarray(A)
    A = A[np.lexsort(A.T)]

    A_t = A @ np.asanyarray(R).T
    A_t = A_t[np.lexsort(A_t.T)]
    return np.allclose(A, A_t, *args, **kwargs)
```

Some results:

```py
R = np.array([[0, -1, 0],  # 90° rotation as an example
              [1,  0, 0],
              [0,  0, 1]])

is_symmetric([[0, 0, 0]], R)
# True
is_symmetric([[1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0]], R)
# False
is_symmetric([[1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0],
              [-1, 0, 0]], R)
# False
is_symmetric([[1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0],
              [-1, 0, 0],
              [0, -1, 0]], R)
# True
```

---

Performance seems fine for 100000 random vectors:

```py
A = np.random.rand(100000, 3)
%timeit is_symmetric(A, R)
# 82.2 ms ± 75.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Is it possible to lose or add lines after a permutation? Your initial array is (3,3), and I see that you get sizes (1,3) and (5,3). Which is your initial array and which is the array after permutation? A after permutation of 90 degrees might be either of size A or of size A.T.

Comment: For me 90 degrees rotation of R gives : [ [0, 1, 0] [0, 0, -1] [1, 0, 0]]. You mean rotation of the matrix ?

Comment: @CatalinaChircu, your matrix rotates around a different axis.

My answer shows use cases for a variable number of vectors.

Comment: Indeed you mention 3 dimensions but I can only see two dimentions in your matrix. Why don't you provide 3D arrays then? I understand you mean the axis z which one cannot see when you have 2D. OK.

Comment: All my matrices have three columns, as there is one point per row in the `A` matrix. That's why `A` needs to be right-multiplied by `R.T`.

Comment: Your solution  to work. What do you want to improve, the procesing time? Save RAM? ther?

Answer (score 2):

It is simple, you transform all the values of your vectors which are `<atol` to 0. You can do that using `numpy.vectorize`, look for the doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

```
import numpy as np

def transform(x, atol):
    if x>0 and x-1<atol:
        return 1
    else:
        return x

myarray = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1 + 1e-4, 0, 0]])
vf = np.vectorize(transform)
new_array = vf(myarray, atol=1e-5)
```

Now you can make your symetry verification.

Please tell me if I answered to your question.

**UPDATE**

I see you already have the function `isclose()` in `numpy`, you SHOULD use it, rather than my funcion from scratch.

Nevertheless, I shall not delete my answer, in order to keep the comments related to it.

Comment: The fact I don't know the pairs to compare is also part of the problem. Besides, your function returns the same given array in your example. I will edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected. In fact, it is the value which is close to 1 that must be changed.

Comment: I added a (hopefully) better explanation of the problem in the question. Finding the pairs of vectors is also part of the problem.

Comment: If I understand well, you already have your permutation operator (let us say switch 90 degres), and you have to make a permutation on the initial matrix A and obtain thus a second matrix A1. Then you compare them in order to check if they are symetric. What you need is the symetry operator. Did I get it right?

Comment: I want to check if the original and the "rotated" matrices are the same, apart from possible permutations and numerical noise.

Comment: OK, so you have to make two operations : 1. perform a permutation and 2. compare the resulting matrix with the initial one. For point 2, I would apply the previous code and then check if `array` and `myarray` are close. Do you need help for point 1? If it is a 90 degrees rotation, you have to create a new matrix and switch the valeus accordingly.

Comment: Finding the permutation is not a good solution as it grows factorially in general with the number of vectors. See my proposed answer to the problem. Can you help me get a better solution?